# How to guarantee that the latest write does not get overwritten by a previous write

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a problem with Firebase writes happening out of order.

I have a function that writes data to a document. The object mutates state then calls the function to write the state to Firebase.

```
function saveStateToFirebase(currentState: any): void{ 
    admin.firestore().doc(`id`).set(currentState);
}

//... application calls these functions with calculated objects called state

saveStateToFirebase(state0);
saveStateToFirebase(state1);
```

The document data should be set to **state1**, however, sometimes there is a chance (due to racing networking conditions I guess) that the document data is set to **state0**.

How do I solve this problem where an earlier write overwrites a later write? Is there an elegant solution with RxJS? I read the documentations for Firestore transactions and I'm not sure if it would apply here. Because I am not updating a field in the database concurrently based on the previous field. I only care about the latest current state of my software.

Comment: Are your states stored as strings or integers?  If they are numeric, it's easy to write a transaction which will inly complete if the new data is greater than the old data.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather make a comment but can't. But can you have 2 observables, one for data stream and the other is the lock state of the db?

Then a combineLatest in the write function would consult both resources before making a db operation.